# Catch a link click with a certain pattern in Windows Runtime

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I am developing an app based on a mobile website which runs inside a Windows Runtime WebView for Windows Phone 8.1. Currently, I am looking for a way to catch link clicks in the app's webview which start with a certain pattern. In the Windows Phone Silverlight version, the following was possible:

In my webview I display links like this

```
<a href="ownstuff:bla()">Do something in the app</a>
<a href="ownstuff:blubb()">Do something different in the app</a>
```

In the app, I catch a click on such a link with the following code

```
MyWebView.Navigating += HandleOwnStuff;
void HandleOwnStuff(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e) {
        String url = e.Uri.ToString();
        if(url.StartsWith("ownstuff:")) {
            // check which function has been called and do something in the app, e.g. open the camera
        }
}
```

Unfortunately, this approach is not possible in a WinRT app any more. Whenever I click such a link, the launcher opens with the message "Search for an app in the store". 
The "NavigationCompleted" handler of the WebView is not called - this link click is catched before any handler of the WebView is called.

An approach which would work is using the UnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified handler, which - unfortunately - is only available starting from Windows 10 in UWP. 
Another solution would be to completely rewrite my website so that the ScriptNotify handler can be invoked - which would be way too much work, since the website now also runs in normal browsers, Android and iOS devices - so this approach is definitely not worth the trouble.

Does anyone know a solution? Thanks.

Comment: What is an "app which runs inside a UWP WebView for Windows Phone 8.1"? Is it a WP8.1 Silverlight, WP8.1 WinRT or UWP app?

Comment: Thanks, I have clarified my wording - it is basically a website which runs inside a WP8.1 WinRT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have talked about this with MSFT for awhile.  Your right, with win10 that's why that event was added.  The best way to workaround it is to change the website.

Comment: Yeah we had to change the website too.  We did it with checking user agent string.  Unfortunately that has its own problems as well. You can set the user agent string once with one navigation but there isn't a way to keep the user agent that way.  We found a win32 API for globally setting the webview user agent and we used it with a special certification process.